# How to render template from controller in Pimcore?

Tags: symfony, twig, pimcore

I am trying to render template from the controller. I have following lines.

```
return $this->render('../Resources/views/Order/notification.html.twig', []);
```

But it is returning me error:

```
Template name "../Resources/views/Order/notification.html.twig" contains invalid characters.
```

Can any body please help me how to render the template ?

Comment: invalid characters seems odd. have you tried rewriting it? also ... I suppose 'Order/notification.html.twig' might be enough, but it's *very* dependant on your installation. is this symfony 3.x?

Comment: @Jakumi I have already tried, it gives me `Unable to Find Template` error.

Comment: Are any of your templates working?

Comment: @Cerad this one is my first

Comment: to ask this again: which symfony version is this?

Comment: It might actually be the .. in your filename.  Twig has it's own approach to finding template file.  Can't test without knowing the Symfony version.  But Twig uses what it calls namespaces so if your Resources directory is in MyBundle then the path would be: render('@My/Order/Notification.html.twig').  You can also use 'bin/console debug:twig' to see which Twig namespace points to your Resource directory.  I don't use Pimcore but I would expect this to be in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Within Pimcore $this->render takes the ***path within the views folder*** as base. It will not work with this kind of relative path.

Within my custom Controller in the AppBundle package I render the views like this:

```
return $this->render("Order/notification.html.twig",[]);
```

Not sure how it works with bundles but according to the comment from @Cerad it should be:

```
return $this->render("@MyBundle/Order/notification.html.twig",[])
```